# Maximize a component as a modal angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an `Angular 5` application with a sidepanel containing a master/detail view. I want to be able to maximize the detail component in a modal dialog, by pressing a button in this detail component - basically the behaviour one could expect from a regular desktop application's maximize functionality.

I have no problem displaying a modal with a component using eg. [ng bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples), however i have many different components serving the role of the detail component, why i need do something a long the lines of injecting the component into the modal.

Basically aiming for a template file of the modal looking like so:

```
<whatever-app-is-injected></whatever-app-is-injected>
```

Well aware that a lot of material is available on modals, however haven't come around anything addressing dynamically setting the content component of a modal dialog.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ngBootstrap? If so, You can use their "component as content" feature.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BODdwmHFEOyHTcNF1PZf?p=preview

Basically, You have to hold a reference to your angular component as a variable, and pass it into their method.

inject their modal service

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}
```

on open, pass in the reference to the component. In the example, the dynamic component they want to pass in as content of the modal is called *NgbdModalcontent*.

```
open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
}
```

Hope this helps :)